# Error with Angular post request, but not Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, post

I am trying to send a post request with information that goes to a token Uri. The information is sent and I am supposed to get an access token back from the token Uri after I get authorized from it. I can get it to work in a jquery javascript plain html page, but not an angular2 http post request. I am wondering if there are any differences between the two requests because I think I am sending the same information at least. The postRequest function is a button and when it is pushed it is supposed to map and subscribe the request. The jquery works while the angular2 gives me this error. All of the variables above the jquery request is the same for the Angular one. Thanks for any help or answers that point me in the right direction.

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}

**Jquery Request**

```
var data = {
code: code,
grant_type: 'authorization_code',
redirect_uri: redirectUri
};

var options;

if (!secret) {
  data['client_id'] = clientId;
}

options = {
  url: tokenUri,
  type: 'POST',
  data: data
};

if (secret) {
  options['headers'] = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + 
secret)};
}

// obtain authorization token from the authorization service using the 
authorization code

$.ajax(options).done(function (res) {
  // should get back the access token and the patient ID
  var accessToken = res.access_token;
  var patientId = res.patient;
```

**Angular Request**

```
postRequest() {
  return this._http.post(this.tokenUri, JSON.stringify(this.data))
    .map((postResponse: Response) => postResponse.json())
    .subscribe(httpPostResponse => this.postResponseJson = 
    httpPostResponse);
}
```

Comment: In Angular, what is `_http`?  Are you using the old `HttpModule` or the newer `HttpClientModule`?

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser's network developer tool and see the request headers, you will see that there is no `Authorization` request (with your Angular implementation). You are sending this as part of the data payload instead of as a header.

I suggest you learn how to use the new `HttpClientModule`; specifically [how to add headers](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request).

You will also notice that with this module, the response is automatically parsed as JSON, so you can get rid of `.map((postResponse: Response) => postResponse.json())` In addition, you don't even need to json-stringify the data payload; Angular will do it for you.

```
let auth = 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + secret);
this._http.post('tokenUri', data, 
               {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', auth}
).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 postRequest(searchText): Observable<any[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = "http:dddddring";
    return this.http.post(url,searchText).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

Try this. This may help.